# How do I get the bitmap header from an openGL screen? (video capture)

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap, video-capture, freeglut

I'm using GLUT and GLEW (with C++) for my project. So what I'm trying to do is to capture video from opengl screen(basically I'm loading .obj models and rotating them).

Now I'm getting each frame with glReadPixels and then I want make a use of this class: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1418/A-class-to-easily-generate-AVI-video-with-OpenGL-a

I couldn't find GetActiveView() function. As far as I understood I will need to use the SetBitmapHeader() function, so I need a LPBITMAPINFOHEADER structure. It sais I might have to fill-in the attributes in this struct

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
    DWORD biSize; 
    LONG biWidth; 
    LONG biHeight; 
    WORD biPlanes; 
    WORD biBitCount; 
    DWORD biCompression; 
    DWORD biSizeImage; 
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD biClrUsed; 
    DWORD biClrImportant; 
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

but I have no idea where to get the info. I feel like to save each frame as a bmp (actually, DIB) and trying to get the header from there is not the best approach...

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: `biSize = 40, biBitCount = 32, biPlane = 1, biWidth = w, biHeight  = h,  bi SizeImage = w * h * 4` The rest of them can be zero. There is no `SetBitmapHeader` function.

Comment: create new bitmap in paint set to deisred bpp (guess 24 or 32) save and use that bitmap header as template where you just change the resolution ...